# Using multiple hosts on cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm using the cx_oracle pip package to connect to a oracle DB at work.

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('1.2.3.4', '1521', service_name='TRADES')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='analytics_user', password='welcome', dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM all_tables')
```

However the oracle db I connect to has 2 host IP addresses.

The original connection string I was given was like this;

```
SERVICE  =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(Port=1521))
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.222.33.44)(Port=1521))
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = TRADES)
     )
   )
```

Is there anyway to use both on cx_oracle? or is there any other package I can use that will allow that? SQL_Alchemy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the DSN string as is, without the `SERVICE =`:

```
DSN = """
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(Port=1521))
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.222.33.44)(Port=1521))
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = TRADES)
     )
   )
"""

with cx_Oracle.connect(user='user', password='pass', dsn=dsn_tns) as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM all_tables')
```

thanks @Christopher-Jones here the details [oracle-net-connect-descriptor-strings](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#oracle-net-connect-descriptor-strings)

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly :) Wonder why I did not see that in the docs, perhaps I should have another look and see if I had glossed over it or something

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: It's in the doc at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#oracle-net-connect-descriptor-strings